# Should we merge [swiper], [swiper.js] and [swiperjs]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

I noticed these two tags ([swiper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper) and [swiper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper.js)) both refer to the same [library](https://swiperjs.com/) and also have similar wikis

Here is a summary of the tags:

[swiper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper) (1,499 questions tagged - 472 questions with no answers)

> Mobile touch slider & framework with hardware accelerated transitions
>
> [Swiper](https://swiperjs.com/) is - according to the creators [iDangero.us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/should-we-merge-swiper-and-swiper-js?noredirect=1#comment919637_419119) - a free
> and ultra lightweight mobile touch slider with hardware accelerated
> transitions (where supported) and native behaviour. It is intended to
> be used in mobile websites, mobile web apps, and mobile native apps.
> Designed mostly for iOS, but also works on Android, Windows Phone 8
> and modern Desktop browsers.

[swiper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper.js) (205 questions tagged - 100 questions with no answers)

> Swiper is a free mobile touch slider with hardware accelerated
> transitions and native behavior. It is intended to be used in mobile
> websites, mobile web apps, and mobile native/hybrid apps.

#### UPDATE

There is another tag [swiperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiperjs) brought it up by [@julioaves](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/should-we-merge-swiper-and-swiper-js?noredirect=1#comment919637_419119), here is its summary:

[swiperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiperjs) (329 questions tagged - 132 questions with no answers)

> *There is no wiki*

Comment: Looks like we'll need to disambiguate [tag:swiper] before any merger or synonymization. Seeing several questions about swiping as a concept

Comment: I guess for that we can use [swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swipe)

Comment: For instance, or just remove the tag if neither tag adds value. Can't do that automatically though, we'll likely need to manually review all the questions, which is going to take a while.

Comment: It seems we will have to swipe the floor with one of those.

Comment: [Swipe] the duplicate tag under the rug.

Comment: @DanIsFiddlingByFirelight [tag:swiper] no swiping?

Comment: We may want to also merge in the [tag:swiperjs] tag as well.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine do you guys decided something on this ?

Comment: The consensus is in favor of a rename, which means a disambiguation has to be done first. There isn't a process for it, and not much can be done automatically on that front. Simply means someone (alone or coordinating an effort) has to go through the questions and retag the non-swiper.js ones. I'll take care of swiperjs -> swiper.js now regardless, but [tag:swiper] remains a problem. can't do anything about it until it's disambiguated

Comment: I can start the process , but there's a chat room to talk about the process? I once received a warning about retagging a lot of posts on a newly created tag `css-calc` , I don't want this to happen again :)

Comment: There's [burnination HQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq), though [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) might be more effective if the goal is getting more people involved. In either case, disambiguations are different from burninations; the goal isn't to tank the tag, but to make what's left of it only about one topic, or make all relevant topics clearly distinct so CMs or devs can use their fancy tools to mass-eradicate what's left. In this case, though, it's likely going to be about removing all the non-swiper.js questions(1/2

Comment: but I don't have an overview myself. We can rope CMs in if the relevant bad uses are trivially distinguishable by CMs using non-contextual tools. I.e. if there's a tag combination that can be mass-replaced with a different, appropriate one, particularly on a tag this big, that's a use-case for roping in CMs. I'm also greenlighting its disambiguation, so unless someone doesn't get the memo, it's fine. Not entirely sure why disambiguations are so much less restrictive than burninations, but it is what it is I suppose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This merge has been completed, me and 
[Zoe stands with Ukraine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe-stands-with-ukraine) disambiguated the [swiper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper) tag, and afterwards 
[Zoe stands with Ukraine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/6296561/zoe-stands-with-ukraine) created synonymous tags [swiper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper) and [swiperjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiperjs) for the main tag [swiper.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swiper.js)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. they seem to be the same.